# where does the SSH private key get stored in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I'm new to Azure, sorry if my question sounds dumb.
I use `ssh-keygen` to create public/private key pair in cloud shell, but where is my local location this private key get saved to? I wasn't prompted to provide a local path for storing this private key, so is the private ket get stored in Azure?

Comment: If you use the Azure CLI to create your VM, you can optionally generate SSH public and private key files by running the az vm create command with the --generate-ssh-keys option. The keys are stored in the ~/.ssh directory.The public key is placed on your Linux VM when you create the VM.The private key remains on your local system. Protect this private key. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20the%20Azure,ssh%20directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ssh-keygen`, by default, the key pair was saved to the directory `/home/user/.ssh` on the Cloud Shell. You can download the files to your local machine via clicking `Upload/Download files` or [persist files in Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage).

[image]

For more information, read [Overview of Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).